# DiscordJS audio playback with multiple streams

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to create a discord bot using discord.js that is able to both play music and sound effects.

The bot correctly plays music, but when trying to play a sound effect during music playback, the sound effect never starts/ends.

I have the following code for playing sound effects.

```
function play(guildID, serverQueue, resource){
    const newAudioPlayer = createAudioPlayer();
    const oldAudioPlayer = serverQueue.audioPlayer;

    const connection = getVoiceConnection(guildID)

    oldAudioPlayer.pause();
    connection.subscribe(newAudioPlayer);

    newAudioPlayer.on(AudioPlayerStatus.Idle, () => {
        console.log("Done playing");
        connection.subscribe(oldAudioPlayer);
        oldAudioPlayer.unpause();
        newAudioPlayer.stop();
    }).on('error', err => {
        console.log("Something went wrong when trying to play sound effect");
        console.log(err);
        connection.subscribe(oldAudioPlayer);
        oldAudioPlayer.unpause();
        newAudioPlayer.stop();
    })

    newAudioPlayer.play(resource);
    console.log("Trying to play");
}
```

I realize that a voice connection can only subscribe to one audioplayer at a time and that an audioplayer can only play one resource at a time. This is why, I create a new temporary audio player called "newAudioPlayer" that will play the short sound effect. I then pause the old audio player and subscribe the connection to the new audio player.

The sound effect is correctly played as long as the oldAudioPlayer has not been used to play a resource before. As soon as the oldAudioPlayer has been used to play a resource, the newAudioPlayer never starts playing the resource. I have checked all the different AudioPlayerStates for the newAudioPlayer, but none of them get triggered.

serverQueue.audioPlayer is initialized when a voice channel is joined, and is always set.

The program does print "Trying to play" but no audio can be heard.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is a known issue with discord.js:

https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/7232

The workaround is to play the local file as a stream if the file for the other audioPlayer is also reading a stream.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).